# Apache Superset error - <html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1> The server didn't respond in time. </body></html>

Tags: apache-superset

can I increase this 1-minute limit for the queries? It is very annoying.  Every time I run larger queries, it timeout. can anybody help on this?
I have already set SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT  to 3600. Why this is happening?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the `gunicorn` timeout. It will help you

Comment: But how ? can you please help? or refer to any link?

Comment: @AamirSiddiqui Just simply add the option `--timeout` to your `gunicorn` like this:
`gunicorn --timeout 120 superset:app`

Answer (score 0):

After installation of Superset run the following commands

1. `python superset db upgrade`
2. `flask fab create-admin`
3. `python superset load_examples`
4. `python superset init`
5. `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8088 --timeout 120 --limit-request-line 0  superset:app`
   *This is the command used to set gunicorn and time limit*
6. `superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger`